# Let T be a tree with sub-trees which each set has a vertex in common - hence T has a vertex in all of its sub-trees?

Tags: graph-theory, induction, trees

The question is:

Let T be a tree with sub-trees $T_1,T_2,..,T_n$ such that all trees $T_i,T_j$ have a vertex in common which each set has a vertex in common - show that T has a vertex in all $T_i$.

The difficulty I am having is that if every subtree of T has a vertex in common say $T_4 \cap T_5 \neq \emptyset$ then $T_4 \subset T_5$ or the other way around.  Now if this is the case for all subtrees then they are just subsets of larger subtrees that are subsets of T, but since all subtrees have to have a vertex in common they would all have the root of T in common and hence T would have a vertex in all of its subtrees.

This doesn't seem right as we could form subtrees of T not containing the root node if there is more than one level to the tree.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: The fact that you're having difficulty showing that the subtrees are nested is because it is not true! A simple counter example could be the graph with vertices  {1,2,3} and edges {12,23}. Then you have two subgraphs $G_1$ {1,2} with edge {12} and $G_2$ = {2,3} with edge {23}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your own argument the subtrees must form a chain under $\subseteq$; any vertex in the smallest member of the chain is a vertex of $T$ that lies in all $n$ subtrees.

Comment: That part I can understand, I just don't see how having the intersection of all the subtrees having a point in common works in there.. So for example if T has branches A and B which are both subtrees, they wouldn't intersect eachother.  The only way I can see is that if in each subtree of T we only have branch spawning a new subtree, but this brings about another thought - can a single branch itself be a subtree (so it is just a tree "stump with a leaf"?  If this is the case than it seems that this stump would be such as the "B" branch above and not intersect other trees..

Comment: @user1922184: You’re making it much too complicated. Once you’ve proved that for $1\le i<k\le n$ either $T_i\subseteq T_k$ or $T_k\subseteq T_i$, you can stop thinking about the tree structure altogether, because then you know that there is some permutation $k_1,\dots,k_n$ of the indices such that $T_{k_1}\subseteq T_{k_2}\subseteq\ldots\subseteq T_{k_n}$, and any vertex of $T_{k_1}$ lies in all $n$ subtrees.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely false that the subtrees form a chain under $\subseteq$. Anyway, the problem is solved at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857698/for-all-1-leq-i-j-leq-k-the-subtrees-t-i-and-t-j-have-a-vertex-in-com .